How do I keep paperspace's gradients' notebooks running after I close my tabs
I am running notebooks on paperspace's gradient. When I book a machine for 4 hours and start running a jupyter notebook in it, if I close my browser the execution stops. How can I change this behaviour? I did not have this issue on google collab pro
I tried free and paid GPU machines and I tried upgrading to Pro account

Answer from the support: "The browsers need to stay on in order for notebooks to keep running. If you close the browser or Desktop application, then notebook will stop running"
